# Removing Space Between Anchor Tags

Tags: html, css

I'm having some troubles removing the white space between these 'social links' that I'm making.

Also I am having some troubles getting them centered correctly in the middle of the 'a' tag. I've tried using: margin: -30; or padding: -30 to try to pull the <i> tags closer to the top, which didn't work!

Why isn't this this working?

Here is my code:

```css
#footer .footer-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#footer .footer-right a {
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="footer-right">
  <div class="social-links">
    <div class="social-row soc-row-1">
      <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="github"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social-row">
      <a href="#" class="stack-overflow"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `display: inline-block` introduces a margin between elements. Give a negative right margin to remove space.

```css
#footer .footer-right a {
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

The amount of margin depends on the font size of the parent.

Another method is to skip the closing tag:

```
<a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<a href="#" class="github"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

```css
.footer-right {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footer-right a {
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.social-row{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="footer-right">
  <div class="social-links">
    <div class="social-row soc-row-1">
      <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="github"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social-row">
      <a href="#" class="stack-overflow"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @WebAlchemist did it solve your issue?